# CentOS pgAdmin page is naked HTML, without CSS and JavaScript due to ERROR flask.app

Tags: centos, pgadmin, flask

I'm running pgAdmin v4.8 on CentOS 7. After last 'yum update', pgAdmin doesn't work. The logfile /var/log/pgadmin/pgadmin4.log has the following error messages:

```
ERROR   flask.app:  make_conditional() got an unexpected keyword argument 'accept_ranges'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/flask/app.py", line 1813, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/flask/app.py", line 1799, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/flask/helpers.py", line 976, in send_static_file
    cache_timeout=cache_timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/flask/helpers.py", line 713, in send_from_directory
    return send_file(filename, **options)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/flask/helpers.py", line 628, in send_file
    complete_length=fsize)
TypeError: make_conditional() got an unexpected keyword argument 'accept_ranges'
```

/var/log/message has no error messages when I request pgAdmin page in the browser.

Removing previous and installing any version of pgAdmin v4.x doesn't help.

Your suggestions/hints will be very appreciated.

Screenshot of pgAdmin page:

[image: Screenshot of pgAdmin page]

Answer (score 0):

I got the exact same error this morning when pgadmin4 got updated to version 4.8.

The problem was with the package pgadmin4-python-flask, which owns the file /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pgadmin4-web/flask and got upgraded from pgadmin4-python-flask-0.12.4-1 to pgadmin4-python-flask-1.0.2-1 this morning and it breaks things.

***yum downgrade pgadmin4-python-flask*** downgraded the package back to pgadmin4-python-flask-0.12.4-1 and solved the problem for me (I also restarted the httpd service after that, just in case).

Arnaud.

Answer (score 0):

As per https://redmine.postgresql.org/issues/4322 - you can now upgrade werkzeug from PGDG repos to version 0.15.x and it works fine with flask 1.0.x